# Copy to clipboard through builtin windows function, not sefmade subroutine

Tags: vb.net, copy, clipboard

I want to add a “COPY” button to my application and I should to enumerate a lot of controls for it:

```
If TypeOf activeControl Is TextBox Then ...
ElseIf TypeOf activeControl Is RichTextBox Then ...
ElseIf TypeOf activeControl Is DataGridView Then ...
ElseIf TypeOf activeControl Is WebBrowser Then ...
```

etc.

But at the same time builtin copy command, activated by CTRL+C, works well and copy plain text from textbox and richtextbox, table from DGV and, say, HTML table as table, not as 
"BODY-TABLE-BLABLABLA".

So, my question: is it possible to activate that sort of copy to clipboard (may be simulate CTRL+C pressing?) when my button is pressed?

Code like

```
Private Sub copy_button_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles copy_button.Click
     SendKeys.Send("^C")
End sub
```

is not works.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For windows forms, you can use the clipboard class System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard

```
Clipboard.SetText(YourText)
```

More information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/637ys738.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Comment: Yes, it is. But, as i said before, it means that i should to describe every control in which a text might be selected. And a universal magic expression, like
    Clipboard.SetText(Magic)
who automatically recognizes format of text is not exists. Right?

Comment: ok, sending CTRL+C in your button click won't work. You're first going to have to determine which control has selected text, then set focus on that control first in your button click event, before sending CTRL+C.

Comment: Yes, sending CTRL+C not works, but pressing CTRL+C works. Why so?